# What is wrong with my logic in a rails hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a setting in environment/production.rb of HEROKU = true

This should change my has_attachment has to use s3 instead of the file system, but it doesn't. What's wrong with my logic?

```
has_attachment :content_type => :image,
               :storage => ($HEROKU ? :s3 : :file_system),
               ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the $ in front of HEROKU in your code? Have you tried without it?

You may also want to take a look at [this config vars example](http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars) from Heroku's documentation for the way they suggest doing things like this.